# Select Mulitple Records based on One record's column value

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table which contains related records (multiple revisions of the same record). Each record has a string field that resembles a date (date, time, and microtime). I want to select all records that are older than a specific date. If a record has a related record newer than the specific date, I do not want to select any of those related records. Any ideas for that select statement? Eventually, it will be a REMOVE statement.

Edit: Some Sample Rows

```
id    shared_id    date                         type      other_data...
1     2            2010-01-01 01:02:03.1234567  original  ...
2     3            2010-01-15 11:12:03.1234733  original  ...
3     2            2010-02-01 03:04:04.5465654  amendment ...
```

If my cut-off date was "2010-01-31", I would want to select id #2 only because id #1 has an amendment newer than the cut-off date.

Comment: could you add some example data from your database ?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [link](http://forums.devshed.com/oracle-development-96/select-distinct-on-multiple-fields-81748.html) helping me generate the select statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.shared_id,T.date,T.id  
FROM table T  WHERE T.date = ( 
SELECT MAX( date ) FROM table WHERE shared_id = T.shared_id )  
AND T.date < 'my_cut_off_date_string'
```

This seems to work for me. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the DATEDIFF() function, check this out:
[Link 1](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

Or this one: [Link 2](http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/databases/mysql/f711.shtml)

Or maybe you can try the classic query (SELECT FROM table WHERE data <= anotherdata), but in this case you need to convert both data in timestamp format

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE from tablename where relatedField = 'relatedValue' AND dateField <= dateToDeleteFrom
```

Something along those lines should do what you need it to do, if I understand your scenario.  If you provide a sample data set I can adjust the statement to more accurately represent your need, but I think this is a good starting point.

HTH,
Jc